# How to provide support for [gallery] shortcode?

Tags: theme-development, shortcode, gallery

I'm developing a new custom theme - and noticed that if a post contains the shortcode [gallery] it gets ignored (*edit*: I mean that the HTML delivered to the browser does not include [gallery], nor anything in its place... I think there's a blank line or two)

My Theme is

1. grabbing post contents via `the_content('&rarr;')`;
2. also removing the standard `<p></p>` wrapper via `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features) does not list this as one of the features you explicitly have to [add support for](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) - but we know the codex can be outdated/incomplete at times.

Anyways, what is it needed for a theme to recognize [gallery] (and/or other such standard shortcodes) ?

Comment: Define _ignored_ ? `[gallery]` remains in page source? `[gallery]` disappears and is not replaced by anything?

Comment: @Rarst: (thanks; I edited the question to clarify) I mean that the HTML delivered to the browser does not include [gallery], nor anything in its place... I think there's a blank line or two

Comment: @FOR have you added any images to the page in which you are using the gallery? [gallery] won't work without there actually being attachments on said post.

Comment: @eileen.carpenter thanks for the tip. I am using the standard post from [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test), specifically the 'Images Test' post. I imported with the option to grab the attachments, and there are other images on that post so I think there's data for [gallery] to work (but will look more into it)

Comment: Seems you had it right, @eileen.carpenter ! I edited the gallery and added images to it: it appeared. Guess the sample data for the Theme Unit Test list does not bring in all of the data needed! Thank you! If you add an answer I'll accept it - for now, a +1 to your comment as a token

Comment: cool, glad I could help. I've added the comment as an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added any images to the page in which you are using the gallery?

The [gallery] shortcode won't work without there actually being attachments on said post.